# pd.read_excel fails with no such file or directory

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this code:

```
print ("received: ", sfile) 
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://xxxx@localhost/xxx")
conn = engine.connect()

pre = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sfile))
fname = sfile.strip()
path = os.path.join(pre, fname)
print (path)
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.columns= df.columns.str.lower()
df.to_sql(file_basename, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

It always worked until today, when it's throwing a no such file or directory error

The file is in the directory.

I tried different excel files, same error.

I tried to get a `os.cwd()` based on other answers but it points to the right directory

I tried `r"path"+filename` but same error

The code above is partly taken from another answer, but still error

I can see a `\\` being used instead of the path, for i.e. when I do a

```
path = os.path.join(pre, fname)
print (path)
```

I receive:

`C:\xxxx\xxx\test_execution_status_details.xslx`

which is correct, but when I read the error, I get:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\xxxx\\\xxxx\\\test_execution_status_details.xslx'`

This is the first time it happened. No OOP. Everything is in the same file, including the function and the call to the function.

I can only think of an error while updating pandas or a similar library as it does not makes any sense

Halp!

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Add `open(path).close()` directly after the `print (path)` line  and see if this raises an exception.

Comment: Shouldn't the extension be `xlsx`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue might be caused by a **typo in the file extension**. In the provided path, the file extension is `.xslx`, while it should be `.xlsx` for Excel files. Please double-check the file extension.

In case the file extension is correct in your code and the issue still persists, **try using an absolute path** to the file to ensure you are accessing the correct directory. Try something like this:

```
path = r'C:\path\to\your\file\test_execution_status_details.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I feel dumb but yes, it was an extension issue :/ I even did a ls to check the files :/

Comment: It happens to everyone 

Comment: Lol. I stumbled upon this question after 20 mins of debugging because I got exactly the same problem